# Receiving a blank facebook webview for Parse login

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate my app with Facebook using Parse, but whenever I login (with and without the Facebook app installed) I receive a blank webview. The only possible "errors" I get when running this are the followng:

```
07-24 16:09:05.103  20910-20910/arcane.com.athletesunited W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
07-24 16:09:05.109  20910-20910/arcane.com.athletesunited W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
07-24 16:09:06.157  20910-20910/arcane.com.athletesunited W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 20910
```

Here is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0+'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4-*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'



}
```

and my Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    Parse.initialize(findopp.this, "{APP_ID}", "{CLIENT_KEY}");
    ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_findopp);


 final List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile");
    facebookbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(findopp.this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                    if (user == null) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    } else if (user.isNew()) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [latest version][(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/) of the Facebook SDK? Can you also explicitly specify a version for the Parse SDK? Can you dig into this a little deeper and try to see what URL is responsible for this blank webview? More info on that [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging).

Comment: Looks like you are trying to load the dialog for an app with ID 422723899. Are you sure your configured the OAuth client to use the correct Facebook app ID? I.e. if you visit the [Facebook app dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/89000000000000/), are you sure that you can pick an app with ID 422723899?

Comment: @derabbink I just got the full URL: m.facebook.com/v2.4/dialog/oauth?client_id=422723899&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A1438132050044%7D&scope=user_birthday%2Cpublic_profile%2Cuser_hometown%2Cemail&default_audience=friends&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&return_scopes=true                                But that ID doesn't exist

Comment: I don't know the first thing about Parse, but I suspect you are incorrectly initializing the Parse-Facebook SDK, using the wrong app ID. This is where you should start looking for a solution.

Comment: @derabbink sorry, I actually found the problem.  Instead of hardcoding the meta-value for the ID, you need to use a reference that is "passed-by" (i.e. @string/app_id)

Comment: @JacobPlatin I have the same issue. Can you please explain in more detail what you did to make it work?

Comment: @Para so when do your id, your value for the FacebookSdkID is probably some number like 142321312312: don't enter the number like that; instead, go to your res/values/strings and make a new value that contains your ID and then use that value in the place of where you had the number originally.